# Android Camera2: How To Get the Current Auto-Exposure and Auto-ISO Values?

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera, android-camera2

How do I get the current auto-exposure and auto-iso values for an Android Camera2 camera session? I am not looking for SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME and SENSOR_SENSITIVITY - these return non-auto exposure and iso. I am looking for the auto exposure and iso values.

Comment: Do you have any references for the fact that the SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME and SENSOR_SENSITIVITY return non-auto exposure and iso?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [Android documentation for `CaptureRequest`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME), these values apply irrespective of whether these are manually configured, or whether the system's auto-exposure is applied (emphasis mine):

> ```java
> public static final Key<Long> SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME
> ```
>
> Duration each pixel is exposed to light.
>
> If the sensor can't expose this exact duration, it will shorten the duration exposed to the nearest possible value (rather than expose longer). The final exposure time used will be available in the output capture result.
>
> This control is only effective if [`android.control.aeMode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#CONTROL_AE_MODE) or [`android.control.mode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#CONTROL_MODE) is set to OFF; otherwise **the auto-exposure algorithm will override this value.**

Since you want the auto-exposure behavior, you'll likely want to set [`android.control.mode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#CONTROL_MODE) to AUTO and set [`android.control.aeMode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#CONTROL_AE_MODE) to some non-OFF value.